# In MediaWiki, is it possible to capture user search terms that don't return results?

Tags: mediawiki

That is, is there a way to log what people are searching for but are not getting any results in order to tell me where I need to add/improve the documentation so they get a result?

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways to do this. If you have access to the Apache server logs, the simplest approach may be to add a transparent image to `[[MediaWiki:Search-nonefound]]` using wikisyntax (`[[File:Transparent.gif]]`), then watch for requests for this image in your (combined, not common) Apache server logs.

You should see log entries that look something like the following, when a user executes a search with 0 results:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2010:18:02:05 -0500] "GET /images/Transparent.gif
>   HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   "http://127.0.0.1/w/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=simpsons&go=Go"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac
>   OS X 10_6_2; en-us)
>   AppleWebKit/531.21.8 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Safari/531.21.10"

In this case, the failed search was for `simpsons`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature for real yet, but you could use a search backend which supports something similar.

The original proposal to implement the feature might be https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T8373 / https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T9969.